# dynamic columns for grid control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a grid control in a wpf view, i read more fields from a file and i want to generate columns for that fields in view model (I use MVVM). So i have a function with something like this:

```
GridColumn column;
            try
            {
                column = new GridColumn
                {
                    Name = fieldName,
                    Header = headerName,
                    AllowSorting = DefaultBoolean.True,
                    FieldName = fieldName,
                    ReadOnly = isReadOnly,
                    AllowEditing = isReadOnly ? DefaultBoolean.False : DefaultBoolean.True,
                    AllowMoving = DefaultBoolean.True,
                    AllowResizing = DefaultBoolean.True,
                    Width = width,
                    EditSettings = new TextEditSettings { HorizontalContentAlignment = EditSettingsHorizontalAlignment.Center },
                    AllowDrop = true,
                    CellStyle = isDiffColumn ? GetDiffColumnStyle(fieldName) : null
                };
            }
```

But now i want in my grid to add 3 new columns with buttons or images. So i think i will need to set the cell template.

How can i do this?

Comment: Creating GridColumns in your view model?  Not mvvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a `Column` with either a `Button` or `Image`, you'll need to define a `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

For example:

```
var templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
var template = new DataTemplate();
var button = new Button();
template.VisualTree = button; 
templateColumn.CellTemplate = template;
```